# How to get SQLSRV on Xampp working with Medoo?

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv, medoo

I got a PHP project which uses Medoo for accessing a database on MS SQL Server 2012. I used to test my project on the same server, but since copy-pasting through remote desktop got kinda annoying and inefficient, I wanted to move on a local system, so I installed Xampp (with PHP 5.6.19 VC11). Since I still need to use the server database, I first encountered the problem that the PDO MSSQL extension is not available anymore, and my script failed to send a query to the database. So tried using the SQLSRV 3.0 extension instead (5.4 thread-safe - why isn't there a version 5.6? Is 5.4 supposed to be forward compatible?), which still sends me an uncaught exception with message 'could not find driver', thrown from the PDO constructor and forwarded through Medoo. I'm not sure if this fails on Medoo, the driver, or something else. Moving the database to phpMyAdmin is no option... Has anyone an idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All information you need are on this this web page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx.

As you can see you need version 3.2 for PHP 5.6 support. I found download link and information about adding SQLSRV extension to php.ini for you.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203(v=sql.105).aspx

Finally you have to install [Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434).

In short, download SQLSRV 3.2, add PDO extension to php.ini (choose right version for your PHP), install Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on your local enviroment.

Comment: It works! I was already aware how to include an extension in the php.ini, but I had no clue there was a more recent version of SQLSRV (seems that I found it on an outdated website) and that I would need ODBC Driver. Thank you good sir :)